# Lotus Notes - Why is my view data missing?

Tags: lotus-notes

I recently just constructed a new view for a Lotus Notes Application and tested it to be fine.

It was supposed to get field data from 2 nearly identical forms and display into the view. The fields on both forms share the same name.

The formula used in View Selection is

```
SELECT ContactName; CompanyName; ContactNumber; CarNo; RequestDate
--comment: These are the names used in both forms --
```

This worked fine yesterday. Also I made sure that each column has selected the correct field to display and I did not change any settings. However, today when I went back to check, the view is all empty.

What seems to be the cause of this?

Comment: If your code is the same as yesterday but it is not working today, then something other than your code is the problem.  We can't help you with that, because we don't know anything else about your setup.  Have you checked your data to be sure it hasn't changed?  Can you get *any* data to display?  You'll need to do this debugging yourself.

Comment: Then what is usually the primary cause for this happening to others?

Comment: That's not even a valid selection formula for Notes. Selection formulas evaluate to an @True or False value. You choose your fields by setting up column formulas for the view.

Answer (score 3):

Your selection formula for the view is not correct. You use the name of the forms in the select statement and then add your fields as column in the view. If we assume that the forms are called FormA and FormB, then your selection formula for the view can look like this:

```
SELECT Form="FormA":"FormB"
```